# Get user and validate JWT token in vert.x

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, openid, vert.x, keycloak

I have set up a keycloak server and I am developing an API which will be out on the internet. The API will receive calls by third parties (clients). These clients will first call the keycloak server with a clientId and a secret in order to get the token and then they will call my API with this token.

I need to see how I can parse and validate this token. This token will probably be a JWT.
So, in my test case, I have an http request having a json web token in the header. The token is provided by keycloak launched in localhost. I have copied the whole token:

```
{"Authorization":"Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJGSjg2R2NGM2pUYk5MT2NvNE52WmtVQ0lVbWZZQ3FvcXRPUWVNZmJoTmxFIn0.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.n1K0KIGYJYPZkjSq1eSg5gWnCAj44mgl4M-GJOlzgCj8y5TGw5OhT7sr84o9Ja9K6WMW3t0ti6feZIgc8mps3RK0HuuXeCNcrN6H2dPEtBphTvfXEUR2iMg83iCmxjhXgXso7oX2vyreJqB6WCCFEPbAQH2e5kHZqv6cfmXRlYU"}
```

I want to:

- Parse the token
- Get the key/value pairs I need
- Validate the token in the keycloak server.

The goal is to protect the rest services and grant access to specific roles.
My application is a 3.4.1 vert.x with routes.

What I have now is an example I found that sets an JWTAuthHandler

```
    JWTAuth authProvider = JWTAuth.create(vertx, config().getJsonObject("keycloak.oidc"));
    router.route("/protected/*").handler(JWTAuthHandler.create(authProvider));

    router.route("/protected/somepage").handler(ctx -> {
        logger.info("Headers: {}", ctx.request().headers().get("Authorization"));
        logger.info(ctx.user().principal().encodePrettily());
    });
```

Keycloak configuration for the call from my API (used for JWTAuth) is:

```
   "keycloak.oidc": {
    "realm": "myrealm",
    "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8100/auth",
    "ssl-required": "none",
    "resource": "app-client",
    "public-client": true
}
```

When I make the rest call in postman, the jvm does not really manage to get in the handler and log the headers though, it throws this exception immediately
saying 
`io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.JWTAuthHandlerImpl
AVERTISSEMENT: JWT decode failure java.lang.RuntimeException: Not enough or too many segments`

Comment: The error you're getting is telling you that the token you received is not a valid JWT, since a JWT requires at least 2 segments. For details on the segments see: https://jwt.io/ since it gives you a good visual feedback on how it works. I guess you're getting something else than a JWT

Comment: The String[] segments array consists of 3 segments (I am in debug mode). I also checked that on jwt.io. I do not know what is wrong with it.

Comment: Do I need to add any certificate or public/private key to the call? For now, in my API, I call keycloak with this client configuration:
`   "keycloak.oidc": {
    "realm": "myrealm",
    "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8100/auth",
    "ssl-required": "none",
    "resource": "app-client",
    "public-client": true
 }`

Comment: The configuration is not correct, we have a pull request to make it strict typed but in the meantime you can see this fully working example: https://github.com/openshiftio-vertx-boosters/vertx-secured-http-booster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look in the source code of *JWTAuthProviderImpl* and I realised that I need to provide the public key in the config. So I have just added this to my keycloak config:

```
"public-key": "MypublickeyblablablavOCAQ8AMvdsvseee"
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly you have an API that makes a request with a JWT in the headers.

In that case you should not be using the OAuth2 handler but instead the J[WT handler](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_jwt_authorisation). This handler can be used with [read only tokens](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-auth-jwt/java/#_read_only_tokens) from keycloak.

It is important to know that as with any other `Auth` handler if the request passes the validation you will get a `User` object. This object can be used to perform [authorization assertions](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-auth-common/java/#_authorisation). Or if you're interested in the original JSON representation of the token you can read it as:

`JsonObject token = context.user().principal();`

And there you can inspect it as you like.

Comment: I have set up a keycloak server and I am developing the API. I will receive calls by third parties. These third parties will first call the keycloak server to get the token and then they will call my API with the token. I need to see how I can parse and validate this token

Comment: Thanks to your code I modified my code to this:
`JWTAuth authProvider = JWTAuth.create(vertx, config().getJsonObject("keycloak.oidc"));
  router.route("/protected/*").handler(JWTAuthHandler.create(authProvider));
  
  router.route("/protected/somepage").handler(ctx -> {
    String theSubject = ctx.user().principal().getString("sub");
   String someKey = ctx.user().principal().getString("someKey");
  });`
ctx.user() is null in my case
How can I get the decoded data of the JWT found in the header as I mentioned above?

Comment: I believe you should provide an example showing your code. Given that your handler is executed the user should not be null since it should contain the contents of the token.

Comment: I updated a lot in the post since my development evolved. Please check it out and don't hesitate to reply. I understand that you are the developer of JWTAuth, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The way you're doing it now will try to automatically authenticate you.
If you want to do some manual steps, use `authProvider.getToken`

See official examples: https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-auth/blob/master/vertx-auth-oauth2/src/main/java/examples/AuthOAuth2Examples.java#L196